# What is the HTML tabindex attribute?

Tags: html, tabindex

What is the `tabindex` attribute used for in HTML?

Answer (score 313):

[`tabindex`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-tabindex-attribute) is a [*global attribute*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html) responsible for two things:

1. it sets the order of "focusable" elements and
2. it **makes elements "focusable"**.

In my mind the second thing is even more important than the first one. There are very few elements that are focusable by default (e.g. <a> and form controls). Developers very often add some JavaScript event handlers (like 'onclick') on not focusable elements (<div>, <span> and so on), and the way to make your interface be responsive not only to mouse events but also to keyboard events (e.g. 'onkeypress') is to make such elements focusable. Lastly, if you don't want to set the order but just make your element focusable use `tabindex="0"` on all such elements:

```
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

Also, if you don't want it to be focusable via the tab key then use `tabindex="-1"`. For example, the below link will not be focused while using tab keys to traverse.

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1">Tab key cannot reach here!</a>
```

Comment: I found out that `<div tabindex>` also works. Is there a reason not to use that?

Comment: Using tabindex of -1 is convenient for things like skip links. You can make an item link to a something right above the content you are trying to link the user down to without having the linked to item itself be reachable.

Comment: Worth noting -- and the answer should probably be corrected -- that the value `-1` is not suitable when you "don't want it to be focused", but rather when you want to prevent focus as result of keyboard navigation. The element can still be focused, just not with keyboard.

Comment: @danijar yes: it's a spec violation. Per https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-tabindex-attribute, *"The tabindex attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid integer"*.

Comment: That `-1` is the end of my research for a solution for items that had an absolute position and behaving funnily when focused by the tab! HOorraaayyyyy.

Answer (score 55):

When the user presses the tab button the user will be taken through the form in the order 1, 2, and 3 as indicated in the example below.

For example:

```
Name: <input name="name" tabindex="1"  />
Age: <input name="age" tabindex="3"  />
Email: <input name="email" tabindex="2"  />
```

Comment: -->What if the tabindex is -1? What does it mean?

Comment: @AlyssaGono you seem to have not read the answer with 85 upvotes... tabindex of -1 means that you cannot reach that element with pressing the tab button

Answer (score 26):

The [tabindex](/questions/tagged/tabindex) is used to define a sequence that users follow when they use the Tab key to navigate through a page. By default, the natural tabbing order will match the source order in the markup.

> The tabindex content attribute allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus navigation. The name "tab index" comes from the common use of the "tab" key to navigate through the focusable elements. The term "tabbing" refers to moving forward through the focusable elements that can be reached using sequential focus navigation.
>   [W3C Recommendation:  HTML5
>
>   Section 7.4.1 Sequential focus navigation and the tabindex attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

The `tabindex` starts at 0 or any positive whole number and increments upward.  It's common to see the value 0 avoided because in older versions of Mozilla and IE, the tabindex would start at 1, move on to 2, and only after 2 would it go to 0 and then 3.  The maximum integer value for `tabindex` is `32767`.  If elements have the same `tabindex` then the tabindex will match the source order in the markup.  A negative value will remove the element from the tab index so it will never be focused.

If an element is assigned a `tabindex` of `-1` it will remove the element and it will never be focusable but focus can be given to the element programmatically using `element.focus()`.

If you specify the `tabindex` attribute with no value or an empty value it will be ignored.

If the `disabled` attribute is set on an element which has a `tabindex`, the element will be ignored.

---

If a `tabindex` is set anywhere within the page regardless of where it is in relation to the rest of the code (it could be in the footer, content area, where-ever) if there is a defined `tabindex` then the tab order will start at the element which is explicitly assigned the lowest `tabindex` value above 0.  It will then cycle through the elements defined and only after the explicit `tabindex` elements have been tabbed through, will it return to the beginning of the document and follow the natural tab order.

---

In the HTML4 spec only the following elements support the tabindex attribute: [anchor](/questions/tagged/anchor), [area](/questions/tagged/area), [button](/questions/tagged/button), [input](/questions/tagged/input), [object](/questions/tagged/object), [select](/questions/tagged/select), and [textarea](/questions/tagged/textarea).  But the HTML5 spec, with accessibility in mind, allows all elements to be assigned `tabindex`.

--

#### For example

```
<ul tabindex="-1">
  <li tabindex="1"></li>
  <li tabindex="2"></li>
  <li tabindex="3"></li>
</ul>
```

is the same as

```
<ul tabindex="-1">
  <li tabindex="1"></li>
  <li tabindex="1"></li>
  <li tabindex="1"></li>
</ul>
```

because regardless of the fact that they are all assigned `tabindex="1"`, they will still follow the same order, the first one is first, and the last one is last.  This is also the same..

```
<div>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

because you do not need to explicitly define the tabIndex if it's default behavior.  A `div` by default will not be focusable, the `anchor` tags will.

Comment: What versions of IE and Mozilla start the `tabindex` at **1** instead of **0** ?

Comment: -1; this answer is a little confused. You mention that "older versions" of IE and Firefox have tabbing start at tabindex 1 instead of tabindex 0... but that's what *all* browsers do, as required by the spec! You also contradict yourself, first saying *"the `tabindex` starts at 0"* but then later saying *"the tab order will start at the element which is explicitly assigned the lowest `tabindex` value above 0"*.

Answer (score 18):

Controlling the order of tabbing (pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to move focus) within the page.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1

Comment: Also, having tabindex makes an element selectable by mouse click. (Adds dotted outlines, can be styled using `:focus`)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 You can can select any input element by mouse click anyway, and the same goes for using the ":focus" CSS.  The tabindex attribute is optional.

Comment: That goes for input elements only. My comment applies to any type of element. See http://jsfiddle.net/XsYCj/ for an example.

Answer (score 8):

the values you set determine the order that your keyboard focus will move between elements on the website.

In the following example, the first time you press tab, your cursor will move to #foo, then #awesome, then #bar

```
<input id="foo" tabindex="1"  />
<input id="bar" tabindex="3"  />
<input id="awesome" tabindex="2"  />
```

If you have not defined tab indexes anywhere, the keyboard focus will follow the HTML tags of you page in the order in which they are defined in the HTML document.

If you tab more times than you have specified tabindexes for, the focus will move as if there were no tabindexes, i.e. in the order of appearance of the HTML tags

Answer (score 3):

It can be used to alter the default form element focus navigation sequence.

So if you've got:

```
text input A

text input B

submit button C
```

by using the tab key you navigate through A->B->C. Tabindex allows you to change that flow.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when the user tabs from field to field in a form (in a browser that allows tabbing, not all browsers do) the order is the order the fields appear in the HTML code.

However, sometimes you want the tab order to flow a little differently. In that case, you can number the fields using TABINDEX. The tabs then flow in order from lowest TABINDEX to highest.

More info on this can be found here [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)

another good illustration can be found [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Simple words, `tabindex` is used to focus on elements.
Syntax: `tabindex="numeric_value"`
This `numeric_value` is the weight of element. Lower value will be accessed first.

Comment: *"Lower value will be accessed first."* - not quite true; 0 and negative values have special meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML [tabindex](https://kolosek.com/tabindex/) atribute is responsible for indicating **if an element is reachable by keyboard navigation**. 
When the user presses the **Tab key** the **focus is shifted** from one element to another. By using the tabindex atribute, the **tab order flow is shifted.**

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing through controls usually happens sequentially as they appear on the HTML code.

Using tabindex, the tabbing will flow from control with the lowest tabindex to the control with the highest tabindex in tabindex sequential order