# How to write onFocusOut for a DIV

Tags: dojo

I tried to use DOJO on focus out method but it is not working. I have the link to work out.

[Click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mnw2N/)

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  on(foc, "focusout", function(e){
  alert("hi");
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="foc" > work on focus out</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)(second answer). To focus a `div` you must assign its `tabindex`.

Comment: Its working !!!. But I dont know how to use tabindex. I tried same tabindex for 2 different div and also different tabindex. But both works same. onfocusout is working for both scenario. Please Explain.

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute)