# How to iterate each sub menu item of a menu by pressing tab key through jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is the code:

```
    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li class="item-1">
                            <a href="#" class="menu">Engines</a>
                            <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                            <ul class="full-sub sub-menu">
                                <li class="col-1">
                                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                                       <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">New</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Personalized Train and Book</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Diesel</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Steamies</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-2">
                                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                                       <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Train Engines</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#" id="abdur">Sub Category Name1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name3</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name4</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name5</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name6</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Rail Cars</a></li> 
                                   </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-3">
                                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                                       <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Other Vehicles</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Sub Category Name</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Sir Topham Hatt</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-4">
                                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                                       <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Basic Engines</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Talkin Engines</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Roll and White Engines</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Battery Operated</a></li>
                                      <li class="sub-head"><a href="#">Multi-Packs</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

i want to focus each item of the sub menu by pressing tab. in the chrome it is focused by deafult bt it is not working in firefox and Ie. I have written following code. Please provide me some solution.

```
$('.main-nav > li').bind('focusin', openSubMenu);
    $('.main-nav > li').bind('focusout', closeSubMenu);

    function openSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('.arrow-down').css('display', 'block').addClass("display-check");
        $(this).find('ul.full-sub').css('display', 'block').addClass("display-check");
    }
    ;

    function closeSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('.arrow-down').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find('ul.full-sub').css('display', 'none');
    }
    function closeSubMenu() {
            if($('.arrow-down').hasClass('display-check'))
                {
                $('.arrow-down').css('display', 'none');
                $('ul.full-sub').css('display', 'none');
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to resort to jQuery, simply define the `tabindex` attribute of the elements in the underlying HTML.

`tabindex="1"`

More on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute), and [**here on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/tabindex) (more info [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets) on exactly what you're trying to accomplish):

> The tab order of the element. The tab order is the order in which the
>   focus is moved when the user presses the "tab" key. Elements with a
>   higher tabindex are later in the tab sequence.

[**MDN also has an article on focus management**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Focus_management_in_HTML)

Comment: where to add tabindex attribute?

Comment: Directly into your html on elements you want to add focus to. eg `<div tabindex='1'></div>`