# How do I add tab support for accessibility to a onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have been tasked at making notification toggles be accessible via tab for accessibility purposes. Googling this has ended in utter failure. How can I accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<!-- Settings - Notifications -->
<div class="panel-body account-settings" ng-show="item == 3" ng-controller="noteSettingsController as note">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="text-center">Email</h4>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, alert) in defs.email">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="emailCritNotes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{alert.name}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        {{alert.desc}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <i class="fa" ng-click="toggleEmail(key)" ng-class="{'fa-toggle-on': alert.status, 'fa-toggle-off': !alert.status}"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I suggest also posting your angular javascript code in the noteSettingsController as this will give a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unclear. What have you tried? What's the current state and the intended result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19000539/847099