# using arrows instead of mouse in html form to navigate inputs

Tags: html, forms

Hello every one I have a few simple html forms that i made for my mum so she can keep a record of the condition of her houses but recently her **osteoporosis** has made it very difficult for her to use a mouse.

She has asked me if there is a way that i could add a feature to my forms so that she can just use the arrow keys to move from one input box to the next and select from drop down boxes.

Is this possible to implement in a simplistic way or is it quite advanced ?

The forms are nothing special im in just about to start my second year at uni and i covered html for 6 months so my knowledge is limited. Here is the link to the forms i made for her so you have an idea of what i mean.

[my form website](http://edwinswebsite.co.uk)   "its made to fit on mobiles but i have made better sites that use JS to redirect to a mobile css and use meta tags, again this one is basic"

Could someone some me how this could be done with a form please :).

Many thanks from edd

Comment: Just use `Tab` key?

Comment: 0_O lol i did not know that thanks pal , well at least there is one easy way, but as i posted it is there any script or function that i could add.

Comment: As @J.Titus said, you can always jump to the next input using `TAB`. You can even go back using `SHIFT + TAB`. When you enter a dropdown, you can already use the `UP` and `DOWN` keys to select values. It's not a good idea to overwrite the arrow keys anyway, because in most browsers you can scroll the page with them (horizontally as well as vertically.

Comment: Javascript Example to Handle TAB and TAB+SHIFT http://www.freakyjolly.com/navigate-form-field-link-elements-using-tab-and-shifttab-keys-in-webpage/

Answer (score 5):

The `Tab` key does this using the [`tabindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute) HTML attribute. Mimic this for arrows presses if you want too by binding an event for the arrow keys and putting a `arrow-togglable` class on each element you want to toggle between:

```js
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-togglable");
    var currentIndex = 0;

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          currentIndex = (currentIndex == 0) ? elements.length - 1 : --currentIndex;
          elements[currentIndex].focus();
          break;
        case 40:
          currentIndex = ((currentIndex + 1) == elements.length) ? 0 : ++currentIndex;
          elements[currentIndex].focus();
          break;
      }
    };
```

```css
input { margin: 5px 0; }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="arrow-togglable"><br/>
<input type="text" class="arrow-togglable"><br/>
<input type="text" class="arrow-togglable">
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment - she can use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to go backwards, and you can edit the form to set up a certain order of elements using `tabindex`.

Start in the middle element and use <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to see how it works:

```html
<label>2</label><input tabindex="2" />
<label>1</label><input tabindex="1" />
<label>3</label><input tabindex="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you nick that works perfectly :), the javascript is understanderable, i have not used currentindex so i shall learn more about it,  thank you again Nick.

Comment: This should be not an answer. please use comment instead of answer