# Assign tabulation order in html form

Tags: html

I have a form in html and I would like it:

1. The tabulator is replaced by the intro.
2. Assign a tabulation order.

Is this possible?

Thanks and regards.

**EDIT 1**

Yes, the tab order can assign with the `tabindex = 1`

But now i need to change the `tab` for `enter`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the HTML tabindex attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute)

Comment: @Kos but i need to change the tab for the enter in the form

Answer (score 1):

```
if(e.keyCode==13){ 
 var ele = document.forms[0].elements; 
 for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){ 
   var q=(i==ele.length-1)?0:i+1;// if last element : if any other 
   if(obj==ele[i]){ele[q].focus();break} 
 }
```

// stolen from https://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/d/181301-advance-to-next-input-field-using-enter-key-instead-of-tab-key/3

Comment: Not found for me