# Give an example of using tabindex="0" in HTML

Tags: html, tabindex

Suppose you want to make a custom HTML tag and use it one or more times on the same HTML page. What should the tabindex be for each tag so tabbing works correctly?

Answer (score 3):

We used tabindex="0" for a custom checkbox created as an Angular component. Now our new HTML tag (eg. ) may be used one or more times on the same HTML and tabbing works correctly.

We set tabindex="0" on the surround div in the component's HTML:

```
<div ng-click="$ctrl.toggle()" tabindex="0">
<input id="{{::$ctrl.inputId}}" type="checkbox" name="{{::$ctrl.name}}" ng-model="$ctrl.checked" />
</div>
```

Comment: You have asked the question and in no time you have an answer with two upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

It should just be tabindex="0" for every html tag, it'll allow you to essentially tab and backtab to the element if you were not able to before. Pretty much for accessibility and UX for navigation.

[What is the HTML tabindex attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute)