# How to give tabindex on div and UL?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing issue while set tabindex through using css style, it's not applied on DIV and Ul Li.

Can anyone let me know solution?

**I tried using this css**

```
div:focus {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}

Li:focus {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Focus not coming on Div

Comment: You can't apply tabindex via css....only in the HTML. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Have you set [tabindex attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112289/what-is-the-html-tabindex-attribute) on those elements?

Comment: if my answer is correct could you please accept it and vote it up? :)

Answer (score 1):

You probarly forgot to set a tabindex like @barbsan mentioned. Second of all in your css `Li` has to be `li`.

```css
div:focus { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
li:focus  { border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">
test
</div> 
<li tabindex="0">this is a li</li>
```